# How to communicate with NTAG213 with ACR122U

Tags: nfc

I bought a bunch of NTAG213 cards and have an ACR122U reader writer. I want to password protect each card with the same password, write a unique ID to each card, and use that ID to compare against a database in order to get an approval or declined response. I've studied the documentation and learned how the cards work via various tool, but my biggest question is, how do I actually send commands to the cards to read and write stuff in the system I'm thinking about creating? Is there a specific scripting tool or software I should be using to read and write or build upon?

Speaking about unique IDs, I've been told that each card has an ID, and that the pages that store the IDs can never be overwritten right? So is it safe to assume that if I bought one million NTAG213 cards, I'd never have to worry about a duplicate ID? If that is the case, is it possible for me to instead just write a program that reads the ID from each card and use that instead of writing an ID to each card? How can I get a program I'm writing to read that ID?

Sorry about bothering you guys with what may be a total beginner question, but I'm totally clueless and really want to learn. I'd really appreciate any help that I can get.

Comment: This is multiple questions. Please ask each question separately. If you have questions, look at [ask].

Comment: I just need to know how to communicate with the cards that's all. :(

Comment: Perhaps you should start with regular android NFC?
See also https://github.com/skjolber/external-nfc-api (commerically available library by myself)

Comment: I don't want to use Android NFC. I would prefer to interface this with a PC and use something where I can encrypt and decrypt data on these cards, and pass the read data on to a script.

Please see my response below to henrycjc.

Answer (score 0):

You should get in the habit of asking individual/specific questions on this site, it's not really a forum.

With that said...

> How do I actually send commands to the cards to read and write stuff in the system I'm thinking about creating? Is there a specific scripting tool or software I should be using to read and write or build upon?

This is a "bad" question in that it's too broad for Stack Overflow. There are hundreds of tools available. Literally google "programming NFC" or something similar.

> Speaking about unique IDs, I've been told that each card has an ID, and that the pages that store the IDs can never be overwritten right? So is it safe to assume that if I bought one million NTAG213 cards, I'd never have to worry about a duplicate ID?

This is a good question.

The ID can never be overwritten on most tags. Definitely not on the NTAG213.

Yes your reasoning is correct, but because the UIDs are not a standardised GUID/UID (e.g. [Universally unique identifier - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)) and the IDs are set by manufacturers (and therefore are open to spoofing and perfectly legal situations where a manufacturer can produce 1 million tags with the same UID), there is no 100% guarantee, it is just statistically very unlikely and a practical assumption that you can make in most cases.

> If that is the case, is it possible for me to instead just write a program that reads the ID from each card and use that instead of writing an ID to each card? How can I get a program I'm writing to read that ID?

Yes that approach is good, but I would consider adding another form of authentication too, because as discussed the tag IDs are not 100% unique. How to do it? It's a bit of a complex question, but if you're writing an Android app, you can simply use the `getId()` method with the `nfc.Tag` class [Tag | Android Developers API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/Tag.html#getId()).

Comment: Thanks for responding henrycjc. What I'm looking to do create a program or build upon one where I can encode a unique ID into the blocks, lock it with a password, and retrieve said ID with the stored password. Basically I'm creating an authentication mechanism. I have a bunch of apps and programs that can read and write to cards fine (GoToTags Windows, numerous Android NFC apps, etc), but I need something that can say:
-Store "17893746" to page 48
-Lock page 48 with password "4758"
and then
-use password "4758" to unlock page 48
-tell me what is written on page 48

...am I making sense?

Comment: Ideally I'd want this to be a desktop solution that takes the hidden ID and compares it to a database, but my issue is actually password protecting and reading the cards once password protected. Writing basic tags with free programs I can do easily. I'm sorry if I'm annoying you with being such a complete novice at this.